# SCSS - Extract common modules to a seperated files

Tags: webpack, sass, gulp-sass, node-sass

In every page in my website I have 2 css files

1. **common.scss** - contains styles for the layout (header, footer, etc...)

```
/* common.scss */
@import "../simple-button.scss";
@import "../blue-button.scss";

/* layout styles here... */
```

2. **[page-name].scss** - contains styles specificly for the current page

```
/* post-page.scss */
@import "../simple-button.scss";

/* page styles goes here... */
```

As you can see, "simple-button.scss" is imported to common.scss and post-page.scss.


Is there a tool that detects that "simple-button.scss" was already imported in common.scsss and won't import it to post-page.scss?

I'm using gulp-sass, but I would like to hear about any available solution.

Thank you!

Comment: What is it exactly that you are tryng to achieve? The thing is, if simple-button.scss contains only styles for let's say buttons you could make a third css file just for the buttons and include it in any site you want as external css. However if simple-button.scss contains mixins or functions you want to use in post-page.scss and common.scss then you will have to import the file in each of them.

Comment: There are components that I'm using in the layout (all pages) and in the page it self.
It might be 50 components, not just 'simple-button'.

Comment: Ok, so then consider to create a separate css file for each component and include it in each site you need it. As an alternative you could create a css file for each site and import those component css files (not scss files) there via simple css import.

Comment: The point is not to re-use it in many websites. The point is that every component defines its own dependencies. I split the [page].css and common.css because I want common.css to be cached in next pages.

Comment: Ok I probably did not explain it properly. By sites I meant pages, my bad. You can of course stil have a common.css and a page specific css for each page. If you also have css files for your individual components you can link all the components you need in all your pages inside the common.css. This way the common.css will be cached since it will remain the same for all pages. For each page specific css file you will stil have the oportunity to include some extra styles and extra component css files that you only need in some pages.

Comment: If you want a tool instead of doing all of this manually you could try a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org)